# "Das ist mir wurst": Warum "wurst"?

Tags: etymology, idiom

The phrase "Das ist mir wurst" means "I don't care", as far as I know. "Wurst" is a very popular and iconic food in Germany. Why is "Wurst" used for something like "don't care"?

Answer (score 4):

Die beiden korrekten Schreibweisen sind:

> Das ist mir wurst. (siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wurst) [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wurst), [Uni Leipzig](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=wurst))
>   Das ist mir wurscht. (siehe [Wiktionarty](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wurscht), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wurscht), [Uni Leipzig](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=wurscht))

Das Wort wird also in jedem Fall klein geschrieben (weil es kein Substantiv ist, sondern ein indeklinables Adjektiv), und man kann es wahlweise mit *s* oder auch mit *sch* schreiben. Damit werden die beiden Aussprachevarianten wiedergegeben, die auch für das Substantiv *Wurst* gelten, von dem *wurst/wurscht* abgeleitet ist (nämlich [vʊʁst] und [vʊʁʃt], wobei die Variante mit [ʃ] vor allem im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums zu finden ist und auch dort langsam von der Variante mit [s] verdrängt wird).

Die Aussprache [vʊʁʃt] ist übrigens für das Adjektiv weiter verbreitet als für das Substantiv. Man sagt also auch in einigen Regionen *»das ist mir wurscht«* wo man für die Aussprache des Lebensmittels ein *s* spricht.

---

**Zur Herkunft:**
Das Adjektiv *wurst/wurscht* ist ein Synonym für *egal*, *gleich* und *einerlei:*

> Das ist mir egal.
>   Das ist mir gleich.
>   Das ist mir einerlei.

Das Wort *wurst/wurscht* wurde scherzhaft gewählt, weil in einer Wurst auch alles gleich ist. Die Bestandteile einer Wurst sind nicht mehr unterscheidbar. Es gibt auch den Spruch:

> Der Inhalt einer Wurscht
>   bleibt ewig unerfurscht.

Dabei wird das Wort *Wurst* ganz bewusst mit *sch* ausgesprochen (auch in Regionen wo das sonst nicht üblich ist) und das *o* in *unerforscht* wird des Reimes wegen (und weil es lustig klingt) durch ein *u* ersetzt. Ausgesagt wird damit, dass niemand so genau weiß, was in einer Wurst enthalten ist, weil eben alles gleich gemacht wurde.

Wenn alles gleich ist, ist somit alles wurscht.

Comment: Hast du auch eine Quelle für deine Begründung, warum _wurst_ "egal" bedeutet?

Comment: Pfeifer sagt: "das ist mir Wurst (umgangssprachlich Wurscht) ‘gleichgültig’ (Anfang 19. Jh., aus der Studentensprache), im Hinblick auf die beiden sich einander gleichenden Enden der Wurst.", https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wurst